# In which country will I go through customs flying San Francisco to Kathmandu via Abu Dhabi?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel

I am flying Etihad SFO-AUH-KTM on a single ticket.  I have a very short layover.

Will I go through Customs at Abu Dhabi or Kathmandu?

Comment: Is this all booked on a single ticket? With the same airline, or airlines working together?

Comment: Was booked on travelocity all together

Comment: First and second flights are  ethihad airways

Answer (score 7):

Assuming it's on one ticket, you will go through customs only upon landing in Nepal and will not actually enter the UAE officially (you remain in a transit lounge).

In some situations you might have to **also** go through customs in the UAE, but in any case you definitely will be dealing with Nepalese customs.

Comment: If he goes through UAE customs, or has to, it definitely will be UAE authorities. Nepalese authorities come in picture only when he lands in Kathmandu.